# Why do we need to subtract by the mean of each predictor variable in LSE's inference?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, estimation, least-squares, supervised-learning

In the inference when we want to model a linear regression using the least squares estimating method, we need to subtract each predictor variable by its mean in the formulas of the estimators we have. For example, if we have two predictors, then the formulas of the model's estimators are:

[image]

So, I am trying to understand answers of the following questions: (no useful answers were found in the literature, so far!)

1. What is the point of subtracting each predictor variable observation by its mean?
2. What if we do some inference based on the estimators defined as if we do not subtract the mean?
3. Do not we lose some information of the variability by doing this subtraction?
4. In the case when we have a model without an intercept, why do not we need to subtract anymore?
5. What is the relationship betweeen adding the column of one's in the design matrix and subtracting by the mean in the estimators formulas?

Comment: You need to read a good overview of how regression with and without *centering* the (subtracting the mean) predictors works. Here's one, get it from your library. *Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting Interactions* https://www.google.com/books/edition/Multiple_Regression/LcWLUyXcmnkC?hl=en&gbpv=0  There are many more.